# can Datadog be used to display the difference in time between two events or logs?

Tags: datadog

I am using Datadog's count API and if I have 2 events emitted with the same tag (like a UUID), I want to plot a distribution graph of the difference in time between these two events. (e.g. I have an API call and corresponding webhook that I receive afterwards, I want to measure latency between API call and receiving the webhook). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Datadog has a **Time difference** function that can graph the time interval between the datapoints.

> The dt() function returns only one timeseries regardless of how many groups are involved. Within that one timeseries, it considers the time difference of all the submitted points across the various groups.

```
dt(<METRIC_NAME>{*})
```

https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/rate/#time-difference